# Is there a way to highlight duplicate combinations of values in two columns, regardless of the order?

Tags: database, google-sheets, duplicates, find

I have a UFC database and I'm looking for rematches. Therefore, I need to find the duplicate combinations of names; the combinations that appear more than once. However, since the winner of the first fight could lose the rematch, I need to find duplicates regardless of the order in which they appear.

This is how my database is structured:
[database example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CI0C3.png).
Fighter 1 is the winner and fighter 2 is the loser.

Here is a link to the database (got it from kaggle): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/19ISNhYFdGzgLZz1x4h2v_Q5Pq0cofw2rkUtwk3xPXGQ/edit?usp=sharing

Feel free to play around with it.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Here is an example of the result I'd ideally want:

[image example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QX7NO.png)

Just a simple highlight over the duplicates.

Comment: It would be easier to help you solve this if you add a link to a sample spreadsheet, with the link's Share permission (when you create it) set to "Anyone with the link..." and "Editor." That way, we can test and solve right in the sheet. Given just a picture, those who volunteer their expertise here would have to start by guessing at your ranges and typing out your data themselves, which is a deterrent to your receiving help.

Comment: Gotcha ... added a link to the database now.

Comment: I see you've added a sheet, but it is not yet clear what you want for results. Just highlighting any matches? Or seeing the names listed somewhere? Seeing all information for those matches listed somewhere? I recommend that you add a new sheet where you manually enter a short set of results that represent what you would like to see.

Comment: Also plz note that it wouldn't be practical to highlight different sets of duplicates in different colours using conditional formatting because you would need a separate rule for each colour (unless you expected very few duplicates which seems unlikely).

Comment: Maybe you could have a separate column with numbers in it showing which set of duplicates a particular pair of fighters belonged to. Perhaps the row numbers like 2,6 for the first ones in your example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to give you more precise help, it would be helpful if you could give an example of the result you want. As has been said, if there are many duplicates and you mark each group with a different colour, it can be visually confusing.

Anyway, I have written a couple of functions with [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) and [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet) that you may find useful for your project.

### Code 1

With these functions, you will be able to get all fights where two fighters that you previously define have participated:

```js
function main() {
  var name1 = 'Conor McGregor'
  var name2 = 'Nate Diaz'
  var result = findDuplicates(name1, name2)
  console.log(result)
}

function findDuplicates(name1, name2) {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Ark1')
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()
  var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn()
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, lastCol).getValues()
  var result = []
  for (var i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
    if (range[i].includes(name1) && range[i].includes(name2)) {
      result.push(range[i])
    }
  }
  return result
}
```

### Code 2

With this function, you can add in a third column, the same number for each pair of fighters. This way, it is very easy to change the "add a number" to "paint the cells in a colour".

```js
function findPairs() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Ark2')
  var lastRow = sheet.getLastRow()
  var lastCol = sheet.getLastColumn()
  var range = sheet.getRange(1, 1, lastRow, lastCol).getValues()
  var indexToSkip = []
  var k = 0
  for (var i = 0; i < range.length; i++) {
    if (!indexToSkip.includes(i)) {
      var match = range[i]
      indexToSkip.push(i)
      sheet.getRange(i + 1, 3).setValue(k)

      for (var j = i + 1; j < range.length; j++) {
        if (range[j].includes(match[0]) && range[j].includes(match[1])) {
          indexToSkip.push(j)
          sheet.getRange(j + 1, 3).setValue(k)
        }
      }
      k = k+1
    }
  }
}
```

### References:

- [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script)
- [Spreadsheet Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet)

Comment: I've added an image with an example of the result I'd ideally want. 'image example'.

Comment: The second code works with some simple conditional formatting in the column displaying the numbers. Used the code =countif(C:C;C1)>1. Thanks a lot!